# How do I getInt from a ByteBuffer with only 1 remaining byte (Java NIO)

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I am new to Java NIO and am unsure how to do things nio-ishly.

Assume I have read some data from a socket into a `ByteBuffer` and consumed all bytes but one, using the get methods of `ByteBuffer`. I know the next thing will be four bytes with an integer in binary format, so I want to use `getInt()`, but only the first byte of the int is in the buffer.

The natural thing to me is to fill up the buffer with some more bytes from the connection and then continue. If I understand correctly, I could achieve this with

```
buf.compact(); 
buf.position(buf.limit()); 
buf.limit(buf.capacity());
```

and then read more bytes.

Since there is no method with that behavior, but there is the `flip()` method, I wonder if my thinking is wrong. Are there better ways to do this?

This situation will naturally occur e.g. if the connection delivers a stream of length + data messages.

Comment: Nope nope nope. Read the question carefully... this is data coming in from a socket, being buffered, and it so happens that the first byte of the integer got "separated". The other bytes are coming, though, so it would be wrong to read one byte and cast it. What the OP wants is to hang on to that byte until the other 3 bytes are known.

Comment: @dcsohl you are right my mistake

Comment: After a `compact()`, the buffer is set up to be able to read more bytes.  Once more bytes are read, `flip()` and read some more.

Comment: Are the messages length fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buf.compact(); 
// wrong: buf.position(buf.limit()); 
// no need to: buf.limit(buf.capacity());
```

Please do not change the position. Position after `compact()` is pointing to the first byte after the un-getted part of the buffer - exactly where you want it.

Setting limit to capacity is redundant: `compact()` already does it for you.